# $T$ is semi simple if and only if the elementary divisors of $T$ are irreducible polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that if $T$ in $L(V)$ is semisimple them $V$ is completly reducible in relation to $T$ , , but I have no idea how to make this proof